# coffeescript for loop refactoring

Tags: coffeescript

I am quite new to coffeescript and I am wondering if any more experienced users could point suggest a refactoring for the following code:

```
splitCollection: =>
  maxLength = Math.ceil(@collection.length / 3)

  sets = Math.ceil(@collection.length / maxLength)
  start = 0    

  for x in [1..sets]   
    if x != sets
      @render new BusinessUnits(@collection.models.slice(start, (maxLength + start)))
    else
      @render new BusinessUnits(@collection.models.slice(start, (@collection.length)))
    start+= maxLength
```

There does not appear to be a while loop in coffeescript which seems to suggest a better mechanism.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are using Backbone.js, which includes Underscore.js, which has the `groupBy` function.

You could create a "bucketNumber" function:

```
bucketNumber = (value, index) ->
    Math.floor( index / @collection.length * 3 )
```

Then group your collection:

```
sets = @collection.groupBy bucketNumber
```

Now, assuming ten items, `sets` should look something like this:

```
{0: [{}, {}, {}], 1: [{}, {}, {}], 2: [{}, {}, {}, {}]}
```

From here, it becomes rather straight-forward

```
for bucketNumber, bucket of sets
    @render new BusinessUnits( bucket )
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianGenisio/M8Qcf/3/) showing it in action

Comment: That is a nice answer and what I will probably use but I am trying to understand coffeescript better.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to keep track of your position twice, `x` is enough:

```
splitCollection: =>
    setSize = Math.ceil @collection.length / 3
    sets = Math.ceil @collection.length / maxLength

    for x in [1..sets]
        @render new BusinessUnits @collection.models[x * setSize...(x+1) * setSize]
```

Note that there is nothing wrong with passing `slice` an end greater than the array length.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code, you want to split an array in 3 parts (the last one can have less items). In this case write the reusable abstraction for the task. Using [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore):

```
splitCollection: =>
  group_size = Math.ceil(@collection.size() / 3)
  _.each _(@collection.models).inGroupsOf(group_size), (group) ->
    @render(new BusinessUnits(group))
```

`_.inGroupsOf` can be written:

```
_.mixin({
  inGroupsOf: function(array, n) {
    var output = [];
    for(var index=0; index < array.length; index += n) {
      output.push(array.slice(index, index+n));
    }
    return output;
  }
});
```